# How to get StackExchange to display a list of _all_ of my questions across all StackExchange sites?

Tags: support

So, when I browse to StackExchange, and then login, I expected to see some link that would list all of my questions across all sites. For instance, I have questions in both StackOverflow and SuperUser, but alas, to view the status of them, I have to click on each one of the sites individually in order to view them.  That is a waste of motion for your users.

I must be missing something here. What is the way to get a single view of all StackExchange-type sites that shows all of the questions I have posted?

Thanks!

bg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a Network Profile like on your profile page, clicking there will take you to your Stack Exchange-wide [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/94468/) & you can check [all your posts](http://stackexchange.com/users/94468/bgoodr?tab=activity) from there.

Comment: Thanks Sathya.  I had a mistaken notion that there would have been a head-slapping obvious link entitled "My Posts" or "My Answers" but instead it is called just "activity".  Thanks for clarifying. Marked as answer and bumped up a notch as useful.

Comment: @bgoodr Glad to be of help!